# Define parent div tag width, according to children tags (Using css)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have parent div tag and him must be several children div tags,  I want that children tags placing horizontal.
 count childrens div tags, is not known advanced, on this, I can't set width parent div tag with css, for this I use js

```
var cnt = $("#parent div").length; // obtain children tags total count
var parent_width = cnt * 102 ;  // 100 is children tag width and 2 is left and right border sum : 100 + 1 + 1

$("#parent").css({
    width: parent_width+"px"
});




<div id="parent" style="height: 100px; background-color: #090">
    <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: #009; border: 1px solid #ccc; float: left">
    </div>
    <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: #009; border: 1px solid #ccc; float: left">
    </div>
</div>
```

This works, but I think this must make without js, only with css, please tell how ?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you want the child `<div>` elements to fit the size of their parent automatically. You can do this by setting the `float` property on the parent `div` element.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
​#parent {
    float: left;
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: #090;  
}

#parent​ > div {
    height: 100px; 
    width: 100px; 
    background-color: #009; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    float: left;
}​
```

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/khEKS/

Comment: Thanks, but this works, if childrens total width less than window width, but if we have for example 40 children tags and every have width 100 px, this not working.

Comment: But you want to display all 40 children in one line or you want to adjust width of parent to the width of childrens row?

Comment: I add: **white-space: nowrap** on parent tag and problem solved, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following CSS for the parent element:

```
#parent
{
  background-color:#090;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
}
```

That way the parent `div` will get the appropriate width automatically so that the children can fit into it.

And of course, you have to specify float property on the child `div` elements as well if you want them to be in the same line.

Comment: Thanks, but this works, if childrens total width less than window width, but if we have for example 40 children tags and every have width 100 px, this not working.

Comment: @Otariki: For all the `div` elements to be in the same line, your screen or the parent `div` element must be wide enough. If there isn't enough space, the browser puts the next element into the next line automatically (this is how the `float` property works). I hope I get your problem correctly.

Comment: I add: **white-space: nowrap** on parent tag and problem solved, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> display: inline-block;

Will do work for you.

You can use the following CSS for the parent element:

```css
#parent { 
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: #090  
    display: inline-block; 
}

#parent > div {
    height: 100px; 
    width: 100px; 
    background-color: #009; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```